# How do you mark specific text on file load with your vimrc?

Tags: vim, markdown, rc

#### Problem

I use vim and [vimwiki](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki) and have files that have predictable headings like `## Planning` and `## Todo`.

I want to do something like this in my vimrc:

```
/## Todo
mt
```

which will happen on file load if there is a `## Todo` in the file.

But I'm not mapping a command with `map` or `imap`. It's also not a setting that can be set with `set`. So I am looking for some vimscript keyword that autostarts on file load.

#### Question

How do you search and mark on file load in the vimrc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like something `autocmd`s can help with (see `:h autocmd`). You can have commands run on many different events, including on loading a certain file type. You could therefore have an `autocmd` like:

```
autocmd FileType vimwiki silent! /## Todo/ | mark t
```

You should be able to modify the event to only run this on the files that you want. The `silent!` part is there so you don't get an error message if there is no `## Todo` in the file. The `|` command allows for multiple commands to be run, and the second command isn't run if the first is not successful.

Comment: I changed the filetype to be `vimwiki`, which is the type for vimwiki files. To check what type of file you have opened, use `:echo &filetype`.